# Test statistic for whether variance is the same every month

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance

I have a panel of observations, where there are $T$ days and each day there are $N$ observations. So the panel is $X \in R^{T \times N}$. The question I'm trying to answer is: is the cross-sectional variance in March higher than average? To answer this question, I have 31 observations of cross-sectional variance in March vs. 365 for the entire year. What would be an appropriate test statistic to see if the "average daily cross-sectional variance" is higher than average?

I know that I can use the F-test to compare variances but I *feel* like my problem is slightly different. As I have a time-series of variances and I'm trying to test if the subgroup's mean is different to the population mean.

Comment: Can you not use a Wald test?

Comment: @YashaswiMohanty if I'm understanding you correctly, you're suggesting to treat variance as parameter $\theta$ in the [Wald test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test)?

Comment: Yes, you would do exactly that.

Comment: @YashaswiMohanty thanks for your suggestion.